# Is it a bad practice to force the client to call a method before calling a second one from the same class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

This is a question about design/best practices.

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass 
{
   public bool IsNextAvailablle() 
   { 
      // implementation
   }

   public SomeObject GetNext() 
   {
      return nextObject;
   } 
}
```

I consider this a bad design because the users of this class need to be aware that they need to call `IsNextAvailable()` before calling `GetNext()`.

However, this "hidden contract" is the only thing which I can see wrong about, that the user can call GetNext() when there is nothing avaiable. (I would be happy if anyone can point out other scenarios in which this implementation is bad)

A second implementation I thought of is that GetNext() throws an exception if `nextObject` is not available. Client will have to handle the exception, plus it can have a small impact on performance and cpu usage due to the exception handling mechanism in .net (I expect this exception to be thrown quite often). Is the exception-driven way a better approach than the previous one? Which is the best way?

Comment: Why should the users even have to call `IsNextAvailable`? By rights, `IsNextAvailable` should be private and `GetNext` should be the one calling it, and then throw an exception or a warning if there is nothing available.

Comment: In this example, it does not make sense that the user have to call another method. "Forcing" someone to call another method is not good practice. However, in some cases, such scenario can be easily avoided by good design and exposing the right level of abstraction.

Comment: Food for thought: If you replace `IsNextAvailablle` with `MoveNext` and `GetNext` with a property named `Current` then you have reimplemented `IEnumerable`.

Comment: What is the contract for `GetNext`? *Must* it throw an exception if there is no next element, or could it for instance return `null`? If the latter, do you really need `IsNextAvailable` at all?

Comment: Unless this question is purely academical, @LasseV.Karlsen is right on the money, implementing the `IEnumerable` interface will take the guesswork out of collection handling and iteration.

Comment: Please note that this question can be understood to be about two things. 1. Is it wrong/bad design to enforce an API that requires consumers to call different methods in the right order, and 2. Is this example code an example of bad design. The second part there, yes, definitely. Replace with IEnumerable. For the first, well, it depends. There are ways to structure your API so that the order is not as much implied but guaranteed. You should clarify if you want a specific answer to your specific example or if you want a more broad overview type of answer.

Comment: thanks for all your inputs. I'm working on a concrete case but I wrote the question in a more "academic/theoretical/opened to discussion" way on purpose, since I thought it's something common in more cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This question is in hindsight asking for opinions so I'm torn between closing it (and deleting my answer) or leaving my answer here.

In any case, this *is* my opinion, and only *my* opinion.

---

You should always strive for "pit of success".

The "pit of success" is best described by [Jeff Atwood: Falling into the Pit of Success](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/):

> The Pit of Success: in stark contrast to a summit, a peak, or a journey across a desert to find victory through many trials and surprises, we want our customers to simply fall into winning practices by using our platform and frameworks. To the extent that we make it easy to get into trouble we fail.

The term was coined by Rico Mariani but I am unable to find a clear source for this term.

Basically, make an API that invites correct use and makes it hard to use wrong.

Or let me rephrase that: Make the correct usage of your API *the only way to use your API*.

In your case, you haven't done that.

#### Broad Explanation

In the case of "is it bad design to require consumers of my API to call methods in the right order, otherwise bad/incorrect things will happen?" - the answer is yes. This is bad.

Instead you should try to restructure your API so that the consumer "falls into the pit of success". In other words, make the API behave in the way that the consumer would assume it would by default.

The problem with this is that it invariably falls down to what people considers "by default". Different people might be used to different behavior.

For instance, let's say we get rid of `IsNextAvailablle` [sic] altogether and make `GetNext` return `null` in the case of no next available.

Some purists might say that then perhaps the method should be called `TryGetNext`. It may "fail" to produce a next item.

So here's your revised class:

```
class MyClass 
{
   public SomeObject TryGetNext() 
   {
      return nextObject; // or null if none is available
   } 
}
```

There should no longer be any doubts as to what this method does. It attempts to get the next object from "something". It may fail, but you should also document that in the case where it fails, the consumer get `null` in return.

An example API in the .NET framework that behaves like this is the [`TextReader.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> Return Value:
>   The next line from the reader, or null if all characters have been read.

**HOWEVER**, if the question "is there anything else" can *easily* be answered, but "give me the next something" is an expensive operation then perhaps this is the wrong approach. For instance, if the output of `GetNext` is an expensive and large data structure that can be produced if one has an index into something, and the `IsNextAvailablle` can be answered by simply looking at the index and seeing that it is still less than 10, then perhaps this should be rethought.

Additionally, this type of "simplification" may not always be possible. For instance, the `Stopwatch` class requires the consumer to start the stopwatch before reading time elapsed.

A better restructuring of such a class would be that you either have a stopped stopwatch or a started stopwatch. A started stopwatch cannot be started. Let me show this class:

```
public class StoppedStopwatch
{
    public RunningStopwatch Start()
    {
        return new RunningStopwatch(...);
    }
}

public class RunningStopwatch
{
    public PausedStopwatch Pause()
    {
        return new PausedStopwatch(...);
    }

    public TimeSpan Elapsed { get; }
}

public class PausedStopwatch
{
    public RunningStopwatch Unpause()
    {
        return new RunningStopwatch(...);
    }

    public TimeSpan Elapsed { get; }
}
```

This API doesn't even allow you to do the wrong things. You cannot stop a stopped stopwatch and since it has never been started you can't even read the time elapsed.

A running stopwatch however can be paused, or you can read the elapsed time. If you pause it, you can unpause it to get it running again, or you can read the elapsed time (as of when you paused it).

This API invites correct usage because it doesn't make incorrect usage available.

So in the broad sense, your class is bad design (in my opinion).

Try to restructure the API so that the correct way to use it *is the only way to use it*.

#### Specific Case

Now, let's deal with your specific code example. Is that bad design, and how do you improve it?

Well, as I said in a comment, if you squint slightly and replace some of the names in the class you have reimplemented IEnumerable:

```
class MyClass                          interface IEnumerable
{                                      {
   public bool IsNextAvailablle()          public bool MoveNext()
   {                                       {
      // implementation
   }                                       }

   public SomeObject GetNext()             public SomeObject Current
   {                                       {
      return nextObject;                       get { ... }
   }                                       }
}                                      }
```

So your example class looks a lot like a collection. I can start enumerating over it, I can move to the next item, one item at a time, and at some point I reach the end.

In this case I would simply say "don't reinvent the wheel". Implement IEnumerable because as a consumer of your class, *this is what I would you expect you to do*.

So your class should look like this:

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<SomeObject>
{
    public IEnumerator<SomeObject> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (... is next available ...)
            yield return ... get next ...;
    }

    public IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Again, this is "pit of success". If the class is in reality a collection of things, use the tools built into .NET to *make it behave like any other .NET collection*.

If you were to document your class as "a collection of SomeObject instances" I would grab my LINQ and foreach toolkit by default. When I get a compiler error I would start looking at the members to find the *actual collection* because I have a very strong sense of what a collection should be in .NET. I would be very puzzled if you reimplemented all the *tools* that would be able to handle `IEnumerable` but simply didn't make it implement this interface.

So, instead of me having to write code like this:

```
var c = new MyClass();
while (c.IsNextAvailablle())
{
    var item = c.GetNext();
    // process item
}
```

I can write this:

```
var c = new MyClass();
foreach (var item in c)
    // process item
```

Answer (score 4):

That's just fine. In fact, this two-step process is a common idiom for a bunch of .NET BCL classes. See, for example, an `IEnumerable`:

```
using(var enumerator = enumerable.Enumerator())
{
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Do stuff with enumerator.Current
    }
}
```

Or `DbDataReader`:

```
using(var dbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(dbDataReader.Read())
    {
        // Do stuff with dbDataReader
    }
}
```

Or `Stream`, for that matter:

```
var buffer = new byte[1024];

using(var stream = GetStream())
{
    var read = 0;
    while((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)))
    {
        // Do stuff with buffer
    }
}
```

Now, your entire `IsNextAvailable()`/`GetNext()` could very well be replaced by implementing an `IEnumerable<SomeObject>` and thusly your API will be immediately familiar to any .NET developer.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of them is an ideal solution, where the `Exception` has my personal preference because it allows a single point of entry.

You could opt to implement the `IEnumerable<SomeObject>` interface. In that way you can provide an enumerator that actually does all the checking for you.

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<SomeObject>
{
    private bool IsNextAvailablle()
    {
        // implementation
    }

    private SomeObject GetNext()
    {
        return nextObject;
    }

    public IEnumerator<SomeObject> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (IsNextAvailablle())
        {
            yield return GetNext();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ironically, `IEnumerator` (rather than `IEnumerable`, but it's related) has the same "problem" as the OP describes: It requires that you call `IEnumerable.MoveNext()` before accessing `IEnumerable.Current`.

Comment: Indeed. Hence the exception thrown in `Current` when implemented in `List<T>`.

Comment: that's true, I was just looking at IEnumerator and it feels also a little bit odd

Answer (score 0):

Why should the users even have to call `IsNextAvailable`? By rights, `IsNextAvailable` should be private and `GetNext` should be the one calling it, and then throw an exception or a warning or return a null if there is nothing available.

```
public SomeObject GetNext() 
{
   if(IsNextAvailable())
       return nextObject;
   else
       throw new Exception("there is no next"); // this is just illustrative. By rights exceptions shouldn't be used for this scenario
} 

private bool IsNextAvailable() 
{ 
   // implementation
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for flow control.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen if you look again there is a comment in the sample code stating "this is just illustrative. By rights exceptions shouldn't be used for this scenario". The OP can change the return type of the method, or return a null, or something else.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this might be an exceptional case, whereas the implementation guarantees that when you call `GetNext` an object should be returned. It might be better than `GetNext` returning `null` and you have to troubleshoot a `NullReferenceException` instead.

Comment: In lieu of that comment, please just try to search Stack Overflow for how many that fail to realize that `.First()` LINQ extension method will throw an exception when the input collection is empty. If the `GetNext` method *absolutely **must*** throw an exception if there is no next item, then I would at least implement a `TryGetNext` so that I can write non-exception-based flow control code. However, having to enforce method call order is (in my opinion) entirely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how often do you do a `.First()`? I usually use `.FirstOrDefault()` and test for a null...